Connect socket mobile s700 barcode scanner in React Native
Can we connect socket mobile s700 barcode scanner and scan barcode from this device and get barcode detail in React Native?
I tried react-native-ble-plx and react-native-ble-manager modules but not getting success in it.

Is the scanner using BLE or Bluetooth Classic? Both libraries you tried are using BLE
